# Exporting data from BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to export data from BigQuery and by default the delimiter is comma. Is it possible for me to change the delimiter in BigQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by setting `configuration.extract.fieldDelimiter` on the export job that you insert.  From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.extract.fieldDelimiter):

> [Optional] Delimiter to use between fields in the exported data. Default is ','

Comment: Is it possible for me to set this parameter in UI?

Comment: No, that's not possible, but it is a reasonable request.  I've filed a feature request internally.